# what comes before and after "namely"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, word-in-context

I'd like to know whether there's any relation between what comes before and after "namely." Are the following sentences both correct? If not, why?

> 1. John bought a wolf-like dog, namely, a Siberian husky.

> 2. John bought a Siberian husky, namely, a wolf-like dog.

Consider also cases where a definition precedes the defined:

> 3. John bought a dog of a powerful, wolf-like breed with a thick double coat that is typically gray, used in the Arctic for pulling sleds, **that is (to say)**, a Siberian husky.

> 4. John bought a dog of a powerful, wolf-like breed with a thick double coat that is typically gray, used in the Arctic for pulling sleds, **namely** a Siberian husky.

Are #3 and #4 correct?

Comment: Etymologically speaking, obviously ***namely*** essentially derives from something like ***which is named / called***, so strictly speaking your first version is "more correct" than the second. In common parlance nowadays we ***also*** often use it with the more general senses of ***in other words*** and ***specifically***, but in the specific context of your second example it's effectively equivalent to ***which is*** (which seems at least "awkward" to me).

Comment: Consider also whether both commas are necessary.
https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/namely-and-commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Namely** is followed by something more specific or more precise than what came before.  Presumably a Siberian husky isn't the only type of wolf-like dog, but even if it were, the species name would still be a more precise way of expressing what you were referring to.

So:

> John bought a wolf-like dog, namely a Siberian husky

is correct, but

> John bought a Siberian husky, namely a wolf-like dog

is not really correct.

- **namely**: used when you want to give more detail or be more exact about something you have just said: *We need to get more teachers into the classrooms where they're most needed, namely in high poverty areas.*   *I learned an important lesson when I lost my job, namely that nothing is a hundred percent guaranteed.*  ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/namely))
- **namely**: That is to say; to be specific (used to introduce detailed information or a specific example) *‘the menu makes good use of Scottish produce, namely game and seafood’    ‘Romose analysed the productivity of mosses at a very specific site, namely on rocks.’    ‘Investing overseas also introduces an extra level of risk, namely that of currency risk.’* ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/namely))

Comment: I agree with the *conclusion* here (that OP's second version is at the very least "not good"), but I'm not sure you've exactly presented the underlying *principle* that makes us prefer the first version. I think it turns on the fact that ***namely*** can (and indeed *should*) be replaced by ***which is*** in #2, but you can't do that with #1. And the reason for ***that*** is that ***all*** Siberian huskies are wolf-like dogs, but not all wolf-like dogs are Siberian huskies.

Comment: What if "Siberian husky, namely" is followed by a detailed description of the kind of dog it is? E.g. "John bought a husky, namely, a powerful dog of a breed with a thick double coat that is typically gray, used in the Arctic for pulling sleds"?

Comment: I would find it more natural to say that the other way round: "a powerful dog of a breed...[etc]..., namely a husky".  If I wanted to say "a husky" first, I would say "a husky, which is..." as FumbleFingers suggests, or "a husky, that is to say, a powerful dog of a breed..." etc.

Comment: Interesting. You've pointed out a difference between "namely" and "that is (to say",) which hasn't been covered in major dictionaries.

Comment: @rjpond If you recognize a difference between "that is" and "namely," then Lexico's definition is not very accurate.

Comment: @Apollyon Point taken.

Comment: @rjpond What if a definition precedes the defined? In such cases, could both "that is (to say)" and "namely" be properly used? Consider: 1. John bought a dog of a powerful, wolf-like breed with a thick double coat that is typically gray, used in the Arctic for pulling sleds, **that is (to say)**, a Siberian husky.
2. John bought a dog of a powerful, wolf-like breed with a thick double coat that is typically gray, used in the Arctic for pulling sleds, **namely** a Siberian husky.

Comment: @rjpond I expanded the question. Maybe you could revise your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Apollyon: We're looking at the construction *X **namely/that is to say** Y* here. I don't think it should make any difference whether either X or Y are long or short expressions. So we might just as well simplify things and consider the 4 permutations 1: ***A crossbreed, namely a labradoodle***, 2: ***A crossbreed, that is to say a labradoodle***, 3: ***A labradoodle, namely a crossbreed***, and 4: ***A labradoodle, that is to say a crossbreed***. Where I'd say #3 is completely unacceptable and #2 is at least "marginal". Others may have different opinions though.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica  The "parameter" I'm investigating is not merely long vs. short expressions, but definitional vs. non-definitional ones. "Wolf-like dog," a description that applies to multiple dog breeds, does not sufficiently identify the Siberian husky as the dog in question. So it is not considered a (good) definition. On the other hand, "a dog of a powerful, wolf-like breed with a thick double coat . . ." is a definition. Your examples do not address my concern in this regard.

Comment: I think you're expecting a level of precision that simply doesn't exist here (different "competent speakers" will have different opinions as to what works and what doesn't). But for that specific point I'd say ***An X, namely an [extended definition of X]*** probably *wouldn't* be acceptable (I'd expect ***[extended definition], namely an X***). I probably wouldn't object to either sequence with ***that is to say***, but as a general principle of rhetoric / prosody, you'd probably want the second element to be the short snappy one that rounds off whatever point you're making.